# EVALML used for AUTOML library

Tags: evalml

----> 3 import evalml

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/evalml/pipelines/components/transformers/preprocessing/natural_language_featurizer.py in 
3
4 import featuretools as ft
----> 5 from featuretools.primitives import (
6     DiversityScore,
7     MeanCharactersPerWord,

ImportError: cannot import name 'DiversityScore' from 'featuretools.primitives' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/featuretools/primitives/**init**.py)

anyone have solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do `pip install premium-primitives`? This will add the DiversityScore primitive as well as the other NLP primitives to your Python env.